# how to write "platform_config_file" for TensorFlow serving

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I want to deploy a model with tensorflow serving. In the model, there are some ops that can't place into gpu. While deploy my model, I should config the tensorflow serving config file `platform_config_file`. The most important is `allow_soft_placement`. How to write it?

```
platform_configs: {
    key: "tensorflow",
    value:  {
        source_adapter_config: {
            type_url: "type.googleapis.com/tensorflow.serving.SavedModelBundleSourceAdapterConfig"
            value:
```

And, it use `any.proto`, the value must be bytes.How to write this.
thanks very much.